# VHDL program's (Design+Testbench) run time is 0 sec

Tags: vhdl, ghdl, gtkwave

The program contains two source files: `8bit_PU.vhd` (entity bit_PU) and `8bit_Tb.vhd`. Final version of the program is supposed to read some amount (in this testbench clock frequency is 100Hz) of 3-bit operation codes to `operation`, decode them, apply it to 8-bit `std_logic_vectors` `operand1` and `operand2` (they also change in time) and write the result to 8-bit `std_logic_vector` `result`. The code I have now describes only an adding operation, so the `operation` vector is useless for now.

Here is `8bit_PU.vhd` code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
 
entity bit_PU is
    port(operation : in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0); 
         Clk       : in std_logic;
         operand1  : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0); 
         operand2  : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0); 
         result    : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
         );  
end bit_PU;
 
architecture proc of bit_PU is
        function Add (op1 : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0); 
                      op2 : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)) return std_logic_vector is
        variable res: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);  
        begin
            res := std_logic_vector((unsigned(op1)+unsigned(op2)) mod 256);
            return res;
        end function;
 
begin
 
    process(Clk) is
    begin
        if rising_edge(Clk) then
                result <= Add(operand1, operand2);
        end if; 
    end process;
 
end architecture;
```

Here is `8bit_Tb.vhd` code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
   
entity bit_Tb is
end bit_Tb;
   
architecture proc of bit_Tb is
   
        component bit_PU is
            port(operation : in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
                 Clk       : in std_logic;
                 operand1  : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
                 operand2  : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
                 result    : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
                 );
        end component bit_PU;
 
signal   Clk  : std_logic  := '0';
constant Freq : integer    := 100;
constant PeriodTime : time := 1000 ms / Freq;
signal   operation  : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := "000";
signal   result     : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
signal   operand1   : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal   operand2   : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
begin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   
    i_bit_PU: component bit_PU
    port map(Clk => Clk,
     operation => operation,
     operand1  => operand1,
     operand2  => operand2,
     result    => result);
   
    Clk <= not Clk after PeriodTime / 2;
   
    process (Clk) is
    begin
        if rising_edge(Clk) then
            if unsigned(operand1) < unsigned(operand2) or (operand1 = x"FF" and operand2 = x"00") then
                operand1 <= std_logic_vector((unsigned(operand1)+1) mod 256);
            else
                operand2 <= std_logic_vector((unsigned(operand2)+1) mod 256);
            end if; 
        end if; 
end process;
   
end architecture;
```

Analysis and compilation process:

```
$ ghdl -s 8bit_PU.vhd
$ ghdl -s 8bit_Tb.vhd
$ ghdl -a 8bit_PU.vhd
$ ghdl -a 8bit_Tb.vhd
$ ghdl -e bit_PU
$ ghdl -r bit_PU --vcd=2nd_circuit.vcd
```

Execution:

```
$ gtkwave 2nd_circuit.vcd

GTKWave Analyzer v3.3.118 (w)1999-2023 BSI

[0] start time.
[0] end time.
```

As you can see, program has 0 sec runtime.

I tested both files separately (testbench simulation in 8bit_PU.vhd file; testbench run only) and they worked correctly, so I suppose, that there is some problem in the way I import PU's ports in the testbench. Then I tried to import PU's ports using `work` library:

```
---
architecture proc of bit_Tb is
 signal   Clk  : std_logic  := '0';
 constant Freq : integer    := 100;
 constant PeriodTime : time := 1000 ms / Freq;
 signal   operation  : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0) := "000";
 signal   result     : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
 signal   operand1   : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
 signal   operand2   : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
 begin
     
      i_bit_PU: entity work.bit_PU(proc) --here
      port map(Clk => Clk,
       operation => operation,
       operand1  => operand1,
       operand2  => operand2,
       result    => result);
---
```

But, that also didn't help.

Comment: Arithmetic operations using package numeric_std will produce an output length here equal to the length of the longest operand. No need to use the modulus operator.

Comment: You should be elaborating and simulating the testbench, while your command line summary shows you are trying to simulate the model directly. Without stimuli it will not proceed after initialization and stop saving signal events at TIME = zero. You may want to provide a --stoptime to ghdl to prevent overflow in gtkwave.

Comment: Let me reinforce what @user16145658 said, you will want to provide a `--stoptime` as my read of your testbench says it generates stimulus forever and never stops.

Comment: Forever? Not quite. A simulation runs until TIME'HIGH ( 9223372036854775807 fs for a 64 bit ghdl). gtkwave however can't deal with simulation times approaching that due to buffer allocation granularity and number of events. The GUI may crash. Without --stop-time ghdl will produce ~93 MB for the VCD file (UNIX End of Line) and complete with a last event time of `#9223300000000000000` (fs). However gtkwave 3.4.0 will balk (or crash for earlier versions).

Answer (score 0):

Your testbench process currently is generating waveforms forever.   You would be better served by a test case generator that is more algorithmic.   Such as:

```
    process 
    begin
      for i in 1 to 512 loop 
        if i mod 2 = 1 then 
          operand2 <= std_logic_vector((unsigned(operand2)+1) mod 256);
        else 
          operand1 <= std_logic_vector((unsigned(operand1)+1) mod 256);
        end if ; 
        wait until rising_edge(clk) ; 
     end loop ;

     -- stop your test case
     std.env.stop ; 
   end process ;
```

If you did this, you would not need the `--stoptime` with GHDL as it would simply run until it hit the stop.

In your testbenches, if you are doing math on std_logic_vector, I recommend that you use `numeric_std_unsigned` instead of all the type conversion gymnastics.  Also as @user16145658 mentioned, you don't need the mod 256 as numeric_std family of packages results are always the same size as the largest argument.  This will reduce your code to:

```
    process 
    begin
      for i in 1 to 512 loop 
        if i mod 2 = 1 then 
          operand2 <= operand2 + 1;
        else 
          operand1 <= operand1 + 1 ;
        end if ; 
        wait until rising_edge(clk) ; 
     end loop ;

     -- stop your test case
     std.env.stop ; -- VHDL-2008, so be sure to enable it.
   end process ;
```

This sort of thinking will get you started toward thinking about how to write test cases.

Comment: Procedure stop requires -2008 or later (e.g. --std=08). You could also stop the clock (`Clk <= not Clk after PeriodTime / 2 when now < STOP_TIME;` for `constant STOP_TIME: time := (2 ** operand1'length + 2 ** operand2'length) * PeriodTime + PeriodTime/2;` for example).

Comment: @user16145658   Using a clock killer as you suggest will cost me something in simulation.   Without VHDL-2008 (which I suspect all simulators including XSIM support now), I used `report "Just Kidding.   Stopping simulation."  severity failure ;`.   Yes using `severity failure` has its own distaste, but at least it is not costing me simulation time every clock cycle.